# Create string enum from IntEnum

Tags: python, enums

I have an IntEnum like this

```
class TransactionTypeIntEnum(IntEnum):
    UNKNOWN = 0
    ADMINISTRATIVE = 1
    PAYMENT = 2
    TRADE = 3
```

I want to create a string enum that has the same names of the IntEnum like this

```
class TransactionType(Enum):
    UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN"
    ADMINISTRATIVE = "ADMINISTRATIVE"
    PAYMENT = "PAYMENT" 
    TRADE = "TRADE"
```

The solution I found is to create a method that iterates over the IntEnum elements names

```
class BaseEnum(Enum):
    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls: Type[TBaseEnum], name: str, values: Iterable[str]) -> Type[TBaseEnum]:
        return cls(name, {value: value for value in values})


TBaseEnum = TypeVar("TBaseEnum", bound=BaseEnum, covariant=True)


TransactionType = BaseEnum.from_iterable("TransactionType", [element.name for element in TransactionTypeIntEnum])
```

The problem that I found with this approach is that I lost autocompletion of TransactionType elements. To know what are the elements of TransactionType, I have to go into TransactionTypeIntEnum.

Is there a way to create the string enum withut losing autocompletion?

Comment: Why don't you just declare a separate `TransactionType(StrEnum)` ?

Comment: The IntEnum is from a package, and if it changes I have to manually change the StrEnum, and I don't want to do that.

Comment: `TransactionType = Enum('TransactionType', {e.name : e.name for e in TransactionTypeIntEnum})`?

Comment: @bb1 thanks, it's simpler but I still can't get autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using enum module. Also you can directly define string-based enum names.

```
from enum import Enum
class TransactionType(Enum):
    UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN"
    ADMINISTRATIVE = "ADMINISTRATIVE"
    PAYMENT = "PAYMENT" 
    TRADE = "TRADE"
```

and you can use the above like ->

```
print(TransactionType.UNKNOWN.value)
```

You can even iterate through, this approch will allow you to define string based enum without losing auto complete and is more straightforward than creating another method for it.

Comment: This is exactly what I want **avoid** to do

Comment: Ok, kindly let me know why so? The above will maintain your autocompletion along with String enum.

Comment: If the int enum changes I will have to change the string enum manually, and don't want to do that